# Javascript Checkbox function: "missing : after property id"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to javascript, I can't seem to figure out what I am missing. I was experimenting with the ajax functions from jquery. I got stuck on this piece of code. The idea is that when a checkbox is checked, it executes a php script and outputs the status of that script to the "Status" div.

I've spent the last hour looking over my code and I can't see that I missed anything. Of course it probably doesn't help that my javascript skills are pretty low.

```
function playback(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"ChangePlayback.php",
    type: "GET",
    if((document).getElementById('LoopPlayback').checked)
    {
      data: "playback=1",
    }
    else
    {
      data: "playback=0",
    }
    success:function(result){
      $("#Status").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

I get the following error with firebug:

```
missing : after property id
[Break On This Error] if((document).getElementById('LoopPlayback').checked)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have the if statement mixed in with the ajax options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refacor a bit; The if needs to be in the assignment, not like a CASE statement in SQL:

```
...
'data': 'playback=' + (document.getElementById('LoopPlayback').checked ? '1' : '0'),
...
```

This is an inline ternary statement. Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the structure, you can store the prefs then `.extend()` them:

```
var ajaxConfig = {
  'url': 'CHangePlayback.php',
  'type': 'GET',
  'data': 'playback=0',
  'success': function(result){
    $('#status').html(result);
  }
};
if (document.getElementById('LoopPlayback').checked){
  ajaxConfig = $.extend(ajaxConfig,{ 'data': 'playback=1' });
}

$.ajax(ajaxConfig);
```

And of course the simpler method to this is just making a `data` variable and placing it within the configuration after:

```
var data = 'playback=0';
if (document.getElementById('LoopPlayback')){
  data = 'playback=1';
}

$.ajax({
  ...
  'data': data,
  ...
});
```

Comment: And this is why I love stackoverflow. I doubt I would have figured that out. This works exactly like I was hoping.

Answer (score 2):

You can change it to this so it does the 'if' inline:

```
function playback(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"ChangePlayback.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "playback=" + (document.getElementById('LoopPlayback').checked ? "1" : "0"),    
    success:function(result){
      $("#Status").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
function playback(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"ChangePlayback.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: $('LoopPlayback').val() ? "playback=1" : "playback=0",
    success:function(result){
      $("#Status").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

This is object and you can not write code between fields:

```
{
    url:...,
    type:...,
    data:...,
    success:...
 }
```

Comment: +1, good use of native `.val` (even though it loads a heaver jQuery object. ;-p)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an if statement in the middle of an object literal. Move it out of the ajax options literal:

```
function playback(){
    var data;

    if(document.getElementById('LoopPlayback').checked) {
        data = "playback=1";
    } else {
        data = "playback=0";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"ChangePlayback.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        success:function(result){
            $("#Status").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or use jquery to do that

```
 if ($('#LoopPlayback').is(':checked'))
  //your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner using more of jQuery's awesomeness:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ChangePlayback.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "playback=" + ($("#LoopPlayback").is(":checked") ? "1" : "0"),
    success:function(result){
        $("#Status").html(result);
    }
});
```